# Composer PSR-4 autoload is not working after trying multiple methods and tutorials

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I was making a composer library for functionality of my framework, but I got stuck on this problem, the problem is with autoloading with psr-4.

### My Configuration

I have the following structure

```
├───src
├───test
└───vendor
    ├───composer
    ├───symfony
    │   ├───polyfill-ctype
    │   └───polyfill-mbstring
    │       └───Resources
    │           └───unidata
    ├───twig
    │   └───twig
    │       ├───doc
    │       │   ├───filters
    │       │   ├───functions
    │       │   ├───tags
    │       │   └───tests
    │       └───src
    │           ├───Cache
    │           ├───Error
    │           ├───Extension
    │           ├───Loader
    │           ├───Node
    │           │   └───Expression
    │           │       ├───Binary
    │           │       ├───Filter
    │           │       ├───Test
    │           │       └───Unary
    │           ├───NodeVisitor
    │           ├───Profiler
    │           │   ├───Dumper
    │           │   ├───Node
    │           │   └───NodeVisitor
    │           ├───RuntimeLoader
    │           ├───Sandbox
    │           ├───Test
    │           ├───TokenParser
    │           └───Util
    └───xenframe
        └───hello
            └───src
```

The last folder is my library with the hello folder in it.

inside of the root of the hello folder I have a `composer.json` and a `src` folder.

**composer.json**

```json
{
    "name": "xenframe/hello",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "XENONMC",
            "email": "support@xenonmc.xyz"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
    
    
    },
    "autoload": {

      "psr-4": {
      
        "hello\\": "/src"
      
      }

    }

}
```

Inside of the `src/` folder is the main file - > `index.php`.

**index.php**

```php
<?php

namespace xenframe\hello;

class App {

function __construct() {

echo "object constructed";

}

}

echo "hello world was loaded";
```

Now, the usage is in my root `index.php`.

**index.php**

```php
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$root = str_replace('\\', '/', __DIR__);

// setup composer autoloader
require_once $root . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// visit us as https://xenonmc.xyz

use xenframe\hello\App;

$hi = new App();
```

### What I tried

o) used psr-4 like the following `"xenframe\\hello": "src/"`.
o) used class paths, I don't like this one because psr-4 is the recommended standard of composer.
o) using psr-0, I didn't pick this one either as there was a lot of verbose.

Thanks!

Comment: When you run `composer update`, what's the error...?

Comment: Its locally installed and I see no errors, I tried `composer dumpautoload` to re generation the autoload composer.json.

Comment: I think it should be "xenframe\\hello\\": "xenframe/hello/src/"

Comment: Oh, I was just testing your code. I have to rename `index.php` with in `src` to `App.php` which relates to class name in the file. Also used `"xenframe\\hello\\": "src/"` in `psr-4` section in `composer.json`, and it started working.

Comment: What have you tried to make your code PSR4 compliant? If there is any error message given, please edit your question to contain it - I would assume that it contains a hint about what is going wrong

Comment: @NicoHaase there are no errors

Comment: You have a problem, but everything is working? That sounds strange

Comment: @NicoHaase well sinse UmairKhan pointed out that i have to match the class nmes i think i kno why hwe got no errors, its because psr-4 not found does not need to give errors cus the library was loaded anyways, if the propper class wasnt found it just skiped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While testing the given code, the problem was resolved by renaming `index.php` within `src` to `App.php` which relates to class name in the file. Also used `"xenframe\\hello\\": "src/"` in `psr-4` section in `composer.json`.

Also its worth mentioning that while composer was unable to autoload required class, due to PSR-4 non compliance, no error was reported by composer.

The problems were:

1. The filename of class was not properly compliant with [PSR-4 specifications](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). From [section 2.3.3](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#2-specification)

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in `.php`. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

2. The `namespace` mentioned in `psr-4` section in `composer.json` was not matching the `namespace` used in class file. From [Composer's PSR-4 Schema](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4)

> Under the `psr-4` key you define a mapping from namespaces to paths, relative to the package root. When autoloading a class like `Foo\\Bar\\Baz` a namespace prefix `Foo\\` pointing to a directory `src/` means that the autoloader will look for a file named `src/Bar/Baz.php` and include it if present.